# how to remove grafana config completely

Tags: config, grafana

I installed grafana on macOS via brew command, and the grafana is running locally on http://localhost:3000/. Later I uninstalled local grafana.
Our team has grafana running in AWS and it sends alert email when triggered. But when I click link on that email, it always directs me to http://localhost:3000/, how to resolve this? Team has a lot of alerts, I don't want to locate the alert manually every time, how to fix that? Thanks!

```
I think it's grafana config 
https://community.grafana.com/t/right-ip-address-instead-of-localhost-in-mail-alerts/36677
```

Comment: My guess is that the fact that you are being directed to `http://localhost:3000/` has nothing to do with if Grafana is installed or not.  What does "click on that email" mean?  Do you mean that you are clicking on a web link in the email?  If so, you should be able to right click on that link and get the URL behind the link.  What is that URL?  Maybe it's `http://localhost:3000/`.  If not, then whatever it is should give a better idea of what is going on.  If you aren't clicking on a link, please explain what "click on that email" means.

Comment: On the email I got, it has a button "Go to the alert page". you're right, when I hover on the button, the url starts with  http://localhost:3000/, which is wrong, do you know how to fix that? thanks